# Error when doing a build in a next js component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a component in next js, it is quite extensive so I am going to put the part that is failing me.
To say that the code works with npm run dev, the problem is when I do an npm next build that I receive this error

```
// @ts-ignore
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

 const formData = {
    country: selectedCountry,
    brand: selectedBrand,
    carModel: selectedCarModel,
    charger : selectedCharger,
    switchValueIni: switchValueIni,
    switchValueEnd: switchValueEnd,
    };

 fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/calculate-cost', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            setApiResult(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            setSubmitting(false);
        });
};
```

This is the part that fails, when rendering

```
                     {apiResult && (
                            <div className="mt-4 border border-blue-500 rounded p-4">
                                <span className="font-bold">Resultado:</span>
                                <div>Kw necesarios: {apiResult.kwneed}</div>
                                <div>Coste: {apiResult.cost}</div>
                            </div>
                        )}
```

The error I get when trying to do the next build is this

[image]

It is a project created with next js using react components and I have the problem that I describe above.

---

To answer abgregs, I have modified the code and have it like this, but it still gives the same error when trying to do a build.

```
"use client";

// Home.js
 

export default function Home() {
    const [apiResult, setApiResult] = useState(null);

    // @ts-ignore
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const formData = {
            country: selectedCountry,
            brand: selectedBrand,
            carModel: selectedCarModel,
            charger : selectedCharger,
            switchValueIni: switchValueIni,
            switchValueEnd: switchValueEnd,
        };

        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/calculate-cost', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setApiResult(data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setSubmitting(false);
            });
    };


    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <Content>
                        {apiResult && (
                            <div className="mt-4 border border-blue-500 rounded p-4">
                                <span className="font-bold">Resultado:</span>
                                <div>Kw necesarios: {apiResult?.kwneed}</div>
                                <div>Coste: {apiResult?.cost}</div>
                            </div>
                        )}

                    </form>
                    <HomeContent/>
                </main>
            </Content>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );

}
```

Comment: Supposing that `apiResult` type definition is correct try adding an interrogation: `apiResult?.kwneed`

Comment: TS is inferring that `apiResult` is of type never which is generally reserved for the return type of a function that always throws an error or runs indefinitely. It looks like you expect `apiResult` to be your resolved promise, but you need to check where `apiResult` is actually defined in `page.tsx` to understand why.

Comment: Thanks, tried putting apiResult.kwneed, I get the same result

Type error: Property 'kwneed' does not exist on type 'never'.